# Using Paperclip with Rails 3.1.3 no file being added to Paramaters hash on form POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, file, post, paperclip

I am having a strange issue with Rails and Paperclip and I am at my wits end trying to solve it.

I have performed all the steps for adding a Paperclip attachment to my model:

FIRST: db updated with "rails g paperclip listing photo" followed by rake db:migrate, schema looks great

```
create_table "listings", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "photo_file_name"
    t.string   "photo_content_type"
    t.integer  "photo_file_size"
    t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
  end
```

THEN: added 'has_attached_file :photo' to listing.rb model (I have tried the usual proposed solution I have seen, "photo" to my adding "attr_accessible", but this didnt work for be because, as you'll see below, my problem appears to be different)

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :photo

    has_many :comments

end
```

THEN: set up form using multipart and added file_field tag:

```
<%= form_for(@listing, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :title %><br />
<%= f.text_area :title %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :description %><br />
<%= f.text_area :description %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :photo %><br />
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Yet when I try to create a listing with a photo attached, I get the following in my logs **(Note the lack of any photo element in the Parameters hash)**:

```
Started POST "/listings" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Feb 16 16:14:58 -0400 2012
Processing by ListingsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create Listing",     "authenticity_token"=>"L6IH7NffyrCbTO0Me9rFb/M3nB2iHyy9BWfh/86H1lQ=",     "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "listing"=>{"title"=>"affefef", "description"=>"awefewfwefwef"}}
  SQL (5.4ms)  INSERT INTO "listings" ("created_at", "description", "photo_content_type", "photo_file_name", "photo_file_size", "photo_updated_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 16 Feb 2012 20:14:58 UTC +00:00], ["description", "awefewfwefwef"], ["photo_content_type", nil], ["photo_file_name", nil], ["photo_file_size", nil], ["photo_updated_at", nil], ["title", "affefef"], ["updated_at", Thu, 16 Feb 2012 20:14:58 UTC +00:00]]
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/listings/17
Completed 302 Found in 15ms
```

I have performed a few checks to attempt to figure this out, such as adding another text_area linked to the photo_content_type directly, and I am able to create a listing with a random string directly assigned to that attribute, so I know I can add form elements other than just "title" and "description" that are in the params of the log above.

It seemed as though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481598/paper-clip-failing-to-save-attachment) question was identical to mine, because I have the exact same steps and issue, except when I noticed that the log from that post at least has the file in the POST parameters... so I believe that is where my problem lies is that my POST somehow does not get the file_field input in its Params.

Fwiw, I have also created a basic test project that is essentially identical (rails 3.1.3, paperclip 2.6.0, all configs the same as far as i can tell) and it worked just fine, so I know my environment is at least OK for Paperclip.

Let me know if there is anything else useful I can provide that I have forgotten to include.

Thanks!

Shawn

UPDATE:

listings_controller.rb:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /listings
  # GET /listings.json
  def index
    @listings = Listing.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @listings }
    end
  end

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.all { render :json => @listing }
    end
  end

  # GET /listings/new
  # GET /listings/new.json
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @listing }
    end
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /listings
  # POST /listings.json
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(params[:listing])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, :notice => 'Listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @listing, :status => :created, :location => @listing }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @listing.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /listings/1
  # PUT /listings/1.json
  def update
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update_attributes(params[:listing])
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, :notice => 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @listing.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /listings/1
  # DELETE /listings/1.json
  def destroy
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    @listing.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listings_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

I got to looking at the HTTP Requests for the working and non working versions, and it seems that something on the broken one is causing the browser to interpret the "broken" versions form as application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of multipart/form-data, despite the rendered forms both appearing to be proper (and the same).

This html:

```
<html class="ui-mobile"><head><base href="http://localhost:3000/listings/new">
    <title>Projectv1</title>

    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param">
<meta content="L6IH7NffyrCbTO0Me9rFb/M3nB2iHyy9BWfh/86H1lQ=" name="csrf-token">

  <body class="ui-mobile-viewport"><div data-role="page" data-url="/listings/new" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 510px; ">

    <h1>New listing</h1>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/listings" class="new_listing" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_listing" method="post">

<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">

<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="L6IH7NffyrCbTO0Me9rFb/M3nB2iHyy9BWfh/86H1lQ="></div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="listing_title" class="ui-input-text">Title</label><br>
    <textarea cols="40" id="listing_title" name="listing[title]" rows="20" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="listing_description" class="ui-input-text">Description</label><br>
    <textarea cols="40" id="listing_description" name="listing[description]" rows="20" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <label for="listing_photo">Photo</label><br>
  <input id="listing_photo" name="listing[photo]" type="file">
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Create Listing</span></span><input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Listing" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false"></div>
  </div>
</form>

<a href="/listings" class="ui-link">Back</a>




</body></html>
```

Generates this request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/listings
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found

Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:174
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:_jqmoblog_session=BAh7ByIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMXNJWTZ3aFNqejJKU3lzMHNWY3NpT0VpK3VpMXA3WU0vZ3FqY3l0akR1TFk9Ig9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiUxOGVmMWExOWEyMTkzY2NkZThiOWJjN2IwMGY4MmJjMA%3D%3D--10e50a0f2b1434f082745442d11009765facf591; _projectv1_session=BAh7ByIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMUw2SUg3TmZmeXJDYlRPME1lOXJGYi9NM25CMmlIeXk5QldmaC84NkgxbFE9Ig9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiU1YTE4N2Y3YjQ4YmViYzM4NWE2NjU1NmZkZjEwNWNjMA%3D%3D--f98196fadc924fc31a247d6c12b0e192be2ba11a
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/listings/new
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.11 Safari/535.19
X-CSRF-Token:L6IH7NffyrCbTO0Me9rFb/M3nB2iHyy9BWfh/86H1lQ=
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

utf8:✓
authenticity_token:L6IH7NffyrCbTO0Me9rFb/M3nB2iHyy9BWfh/86H1lQ=
listing[title]:efrqwafawef
listing[description]:ewfawefawfa
commit:Create Listing

Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:99
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 17 Feb 2012 04:34:17 GMT
Location:http://localhost:3000/listings/20
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.8.7/2010-01-10)
Set-Cookie:_projectv1_session=BAh7CCIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMUw2SUg3TmZmeXJDYlRPME1lOXJGYi9NM25CMmlIeXk5QldmaC84NkgxbFE9Ig9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiU1YTE4N2Y3YjQ4YmViYzM4NWE2NjU1NmZkZjEwNWNjMCIKZmxhc2hvOiVBY3Rpb25EaXNwYXRjaDo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaAk6CUBub3cwOg1AZmxhc2hlc3sGOgtub3RpY2UiJkxpc3Rpbmcgd2FzIHN1Y2Nlc3NmdWxseSBjcmVhdGVkLjoMQGNsb3NlZEY6CkB1c2VkbzoIU2V0BjoKQGhhc2h7AA%3D%3D--cee3b017f9321c30c99c844dbe220a2e7c0fe65c; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Runtime:0.053807
X-Ua-Compatible:IE=Edge
```

Whereas this one:

```
<html class="ui-mobile landscape">
  <title>Jqmoblog</title>

<meta content="sIY6whSjz2JSys0sVcsiOEi+ui1p7YM/gqjcytjDuLY=" name="csrf-token">

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="ui-page-start" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active">
  <div data-role="header" class="ui-bar-a ui-header" role="banner">
  <h1 class="ui-title" tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-level="1">New Post</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts" class="new_post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_post" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="sIY6whSjz2JSys0sVcsiOEi+ui1p7YM/gqjcytjDuLY=" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"></div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="post_title" class="ui-input-text">Title</label><br>
    <input id="post_title" name="post[title]" size="30" type="text" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="post_body" class="ui-input-text">Body</label><br>
    <textarea cols="40" id="post_body" name="post[body]" rows="20" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <label for="post_photo" class="ui-input-text">Photo</label><br>
    <input id="post_photo" name="post[photo]" type="file" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <a href="#" role="button" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Create Post</span></span></a><input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Post" class="ui-btn-hidden" tabindex="-1">
  </div>
</form>
</div>

</div>


</body></html>
```

Generates this (properly multipart/form-data):

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/posts
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:19656
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryl9GzwyGxhzaMAAAL
Cookie:_projectv1_session=BAh7CCIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMUw2SUg3TmZmeXJDYlRPME1lOXJGYi9NM25CMmlIeXk5QldmaC84NkgxbFE9Ig9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiU1YTE4N2Y3YjQ4YmViYzM4NWE2NjU1NmZkZjEwNWNjMCIKZmxhc2hvOiVBY3Rpb25EaXNwYXRjaDo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaAk6CUBub3cwOg1AZmxhc2hlc3sGOgtub3RpY2UiJkxpc3Rpbmcgd2FzIHN1Y2Nlc3NmdWxseSBjcmVhdGVkLjoKQHVzZWRvOghTZXQGOgpAaGFzaHsGOwhUOgxAY2xvc2VkRg%3D%3D--e6b59d98df882703b2b02ddbe9eea4cfd35450b8; _jqmoblog_session=BAh7ByIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMXNJWTZ3aFNqejJKU3lzMHNWY3NpT0VpK3VpMXA3WU0vZ3FqY3l0akR1TFk9Ig9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiUxOGVmMWExOWEyMTkzY2NkZThiOWJjN2IwMGY4MmJjMA%3D%3D--10e50a0f2b1434f082745442d11009765facf591
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/posts/new
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.11 Safari/535.19

------WebKitFormBoundaryl9GzwyGxhzaMAAAL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="utf8"

âœ“
------WebKitFormBoundaryl9GzwyGxhzaMAAAL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="authenticity_token"

sIY6whSjz2JSys0sVcsiOEi+ui1p7YM/gqjcytjDuLY=
------WebKitFormBoundaryl9GzwyGxhzaMAAAL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post[title]"

fawfwef
------WebKitFormBoundaryl9GzwyGxhzaMAAAL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post[body]"

waefawfwe
------WebKitFormBoundaryl9GzwyGxhzaMAAAL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post[photo]"; filename="paul_jones.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryl9GzwyGxhzaMAAAL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="commit"

Create Post
------WebKitFormBoundaryl9GzwyGxhzaMAAAL--

Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:95
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 17 Feb 2012 04:38:21 GMT
Location:http://localhost:3000/posts/9
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.8.7/2010-01-10)
Set-Cookie:_jqmoblog_session=BAh7CCIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMXNJWTZ3aFNqejJKU3lzMHNWY3NpT0VpK3VpMXA3WU0vZ3FqY3l0akR1TFk9Ig9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiUxOGVmMWExOWEyMTkzY2NkZThiOWJjN2IwMGY4MmJjMCIKZmxhc2hvOiVBY3Rpb25EaXNwYXRjaDo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaAk6CUBub3cwOgxAY2xvc2VkRjoNQGZsYXNoZXN7BjoLbm90aWNlIiNQb3N0IHdhcyBzdWNjZXNzZnVsbHkgY3JlYXRlZC46CkB1c2VkbzoIU2V0BjoKQGhhc2h7AA%3D%3D--ae40706dfb78db19e149df4272663f6c872ee4d6; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Runtime:0.127143
X-Ua-Compatible:IE=Edge
```

Comment: Please add code for your paperclipped model.

Comment: can you show your controller code please?

Comment: @Isotope updated with listings_controller.rb

Comment: Most of my code is very little, if at all, removed from what scaffold generated.

Comment: UPDATE: I got to looking at the HTTP Requests for the working and non working versions, and it seems that something on the broken one is causing the browser to interpret the "broken" versions form as application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of multipart/form-data. I have added the rails generated html for each of the applications, as well as the HTTP Request information for each.

Answer (score 4):

One case in which the uploaded file's parameters would not be part of the params array could be because you are using a component like JQuery Mobile that posts file data via AJAX.
You can use an internet browser developer tool to verify the upload data is sent via AJAX (tools like firebug, ie dev tools, chrome inspect elements, etc...)
In your view, add this, instead of :html => { :multipart => true } (it is already multipart=true by default in a model generated form)

> form_for(@model, html: {data: {ajax: false}})

Hope that helps someone someday!
Best of luck
Yohann